# Potential security risks of giving FTP account and wp-admin to Theme Support team on self-hosted wordpress.org site

Tags: wordpress, ftp, domain-admin

I have a brand new WordPress.org website, so far there isn't any content uploaded.

The hurdle is that as soon as I install the theme that I payed for, it crashes.

The theme that I payed for (Lezada), includes a year of support.

The support team insists that I give them the username and password to an admin account for the WordPress site.

They also insist that I give them the username and password to an FTP account for the site.

For now, I am kind of OK with it. I can create a temporary admin account and a temporary FTP account for them, and delete the user accounts once they are done troubleshooting. There isn't any sensitive data (yet) on my site, as it is brand new and I still haven't uploaded any actual content.

The question is, could trusting these people with admin and FTP access now cause potential future security risks? E.g. perhaps they install some script in my WordPress installation that is a backdoor for hackers later?

I am not a cybersecurity expert. I am just a junior web developer with an undergrad in Computer Science. Please bear in mind my level of technical expertise when answering question.

Comment: welcome - depending on your environ, a wordpress admin will be able to change aspects of the wordpress instal, add plugins, add other accounts, and even go so far as to make changes to the host itself, via arbitrary `php` run on the host. so, you're right to be wary .. how comfortable are you in deciphering the problem that you're experiencing - "it crashes" .. why? what error? can you modify your `php` interpreter to dump an error log? can you delve into the source code? (all of these should theoretically be possible...) maybe you can get them to fix the prob, describe it, then you re-instal

Comment: You (apparently) trust their template(s) that may contain malicious code (e.g. backdoor) to begin with. Since it's a clean install there is no sensitive data to be stolen, I would ask them after they did the install what went wrong and how to prevent it from going wrong in the future. This way you could do a clean install and do it yourself without them having accessed the actual installation.

Comment: Did you really mean **FTP**, or did you mean **secure** FTP as in FTPS or SFTP? Plain FTP is completely insecure and should never be used outside a closed environment.